# Django one-to-one reverse relationship DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

I've got an odd problem here, where my one-to-one relationship doesn't seem to be working in reverse. It's easiest to explain with code.

I have extended the default Django User to add a timezone, as so:

```
#This model holds custom user fields
class TaskUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="task_user")
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="UTC")
```

I migrated using South, no problems so far. It's shown inline in my admin, again no problems. I also used syncdb since I haven't used South with User before, which synced everything else no problems.

So, according to the documentation I should now have a field task_user on User objects, which references the TaskUser object.

If I go into Django shell, this is not the case. (See In[6])

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [2]: current_user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

In [3]: current_user?  
Type:       User
String Form:callum
File:       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py
Docstring:
Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this
model.

Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.

In [4]: for field in current_user._meta.fields:
    print field.name
    ...:     
id
password
last_login
is_superuser
username
first_name
last_name
email
is_staff
is_active
date_joined


In [5]: dir(current_user)
Out[5]: 
['DoesNotExist',
'Meta',
'MultipleObjectsReturned',
'REQUIRED_FIELDS',
'USERNAME_FIELD',
#I have removed many more field here
'task_user',
#And a few here
'validate_unique']

In [6]: current_user.task_user
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoesNotExist                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 current_user.task_user

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in     __get__(self, instance, instance_type)
    277             setattr(instance, self.cache_name, rel_obj)
    278         if rel_obj is None:
--> 279             raise self.related.model.DoesNotExist
    280         else:
    281             return rel_obj

DoesNotExist:
```

I'm a bit confused by this result - it seems like the object has this task_data field somewhere, but not as a relationship? I'm not really sure how I can access it and avoid this error.

Thanks in advance for any help anybody can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify related_name, you’re not adding a field to `User` model. Instead, some kind of descriptor is created so it won’t be visible in `User`’s `fields` property. Having the field defined in `TaskUser` model in such a way means that it is not possible to have `TaskUser` instance without associated user, but it is possible to have `User` instance without associated `TaksUser` instance (the same stays true for `ForeignKey` relations), so you need to ensure that `TaskUser` instance is actually created; it won’t be done automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that was my fault - task_user also fails. I will update the question now, sorry.

Comment: @CallumM commonly, if every user NEEDS a TaskUser instance it can be done through signals, you can register a handler to create a newtask user instance everytime a new user is created, guarenteeing that every user has a valid `task_user`

Comment: @dm03514 Alright thanks, I'll look into that. Really the timezone is optional since it has a default, but the easiest thing would definitely be to create the TaskUser with the User. Thanks.